# NsRegularExpressions several float numbers separate with commas

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsregularexpression

i try to evaluate this sentence:

```
<font color="0.839216,0.839216,0.839216" strokeColor="none" size="35" face="Avenir-Book">
```

i need to extract the 3 float values of the color attribute

with this code:

```
NSRegularExpression* colorRegex = [[[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"color=([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)" options:0 error:NULL] autorelease];

[colorRegex enumerateMatchesInString:tag options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [tag length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){


NSNumber *redComponent=[NSNumber numberWithFloat: [[tag substringWithRange: match.range] floatValue] ];
NSNumber *greenComponent=[NSNumber numberWithFloat: [[tag substringWithRange: match.range ] floatValue] ];
NSNumber *blueComponent=[NSNumber numberWithFloat: [[tag substringWithRange: match.range] floatValue] ];

self.color=[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:redComponent.floatValue green:greenComponent.floatValue blue:blueComponent.floatValue alpha:1];

NSLog(@"color %@,%@,%@",redComponent,greenComponent,blueComponent);
```

i tested several regular expressions but I did not succeed, could somebody help me ?

Comment: You are using **%@** in NSLog for **NSNumber**...

Comment: `NSLog(@"color %@,%@,%@",redComponent,greenComponent,blueComponent);`  

This should be    

`NSLog(@"color %@,%@,%@",[redComponent stringValue],[greenComponent stringValue],[blueComponent stringValue]);`

Comment: @AhmedZ.: Using `%@` for `NSNumber` is no problem at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern does not match the quotes `"` and the dots `.`, so it should look like:

```
initWithPattern:@"color=\"([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+)\""
```

And inside the block, you have to use `rangeAtIndex:` to get the values of the capture group, so this would look like (simplifying your code a bit):

```
float redComponent = [[tag substringWithRange: [match rangeAtIndex:1]] floatValue];
float greenComponent = [[tag substringWithRange: [match rangeAtIndex:2]] floatValue];
float blueComponent = [[tag substringWithRange: [match rangeAtIndex:3]] floatValue];
self.color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:redComponent green:greenComponent blue:blueComponent alpha:1];

NSLog(@"color %f,%f,%f", redComponent, greenComponent, blueComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
testArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSString *testString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"0.309804,0.784314,0.992157"];
testArray = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

now u can use the values from testArray. Also you can convert it into int or float

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *color = @"color=0.309804,0.784314,0.992157";
color = [color stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"color=" withString:@""];
NSArray *arrColor = [color componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

NSNumber *redComponent;
NSNumber *greenComponent;
NSNumber *blueComponent;

for (int i = 0; i < [arrColor count]; i++) {
    if (i == 0)   redComponent=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[arrColor objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]];
    if (i == 1)   greenComponent=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[arrColor objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]];
    if (i == 2)   blueComponent=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[arrColor objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]];
}
NSLog(@"color %@,%@,%@",redComponent,greenComponent,blueComponent);
```

**Output:**

color 0.309804,0.784314,0.992157

Comment: thanks for the answer but gives me this result color 0,0.784314,0.992157

Comment: your color string has same value?